# Matlab parfor nested loop variable access

Tags: matlab, parfor

I need to write a simple nested for loop in MATLAB using `parfor` for the outer loop. The skeletal code is:

```
parfor i=1:M
    for j=1:N
         A(i,j)=myFunction(i,j);
    end
end
```

After this, I need to find the maximum value in the matrix `A` (corresponding row and column numbers). However, this variable is not accessible outside of the `parfor` loop. What is the simplest way to do this? This is required for multiple parameter tuning for a classifier.

**Update**

Here is the exact code:

```
C1=[0.001;100]; C2=[0.001;100];

A=zeros(length(C1),length(C2));

parfor i=1:length(C1)
  for j=1:length(C2)
     A(i,j)=2*i-3*j;
  end
end

[max_num,max_idx] = max(A(:)); %finding maximum element
[X Y]=ind2sub(size(A),max_num); %retrieving location of max element

% Need to use these values
bestC=C1(X)
bestD=C2(Y)

poolobj = gcp('nocreate');
delete(poolobj);
```

This gives the error:

```
Error: The variable A in a parfor cannot be classified.
```

Comment: A should be available outside of parfor once the loop completes. I just tested this by replacing your inner statement with A(i,j) = i*M + j*N; What error are you getting when you try to access this?

Comment: I have edited the question to add the code and error. Please have a look.

Comment: I tried your code and got the same error. I then tried Daniel's code below, which worked. So clearly, replacing length(C1) and length(C2) with variables solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor modification and Matlab is able to understand your code.

```
C1=[0.001;100]; C2=[0.001;100];
n=length(C1);
m=length(C2);
A=zeros(n,m);

parfor i=1:n
  for j=1:m
     A(i,j)=2*i-3*j;
  end
end

[max_num,max_idx] = max(A(:)); %finding maximum element
[X Y]=ind2sub(size(A),max_num); %retrieving location of max element

% Need to use these values
bestC=C1(X)
bestD=C2(Y)

poolobj = gcp('nocreate');
delete(poolobj);
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the minimum value of `A`, you don't need to store all of the elements - `parfor` understands reductions like `min`, so something like this works:

```
A = Inf;
parfor i=1:M
    for j=1:N
        A = min(A, rand);
    end
end
```

Ok, if you want the extremal value and the location, you need to do a bit more work. You don't need to store the whole of `A` though, you can still phrase this as a `parfor` reduction.

```
function Axy = pfeg

% Axy contains the running maximum value of A, and the location
% where it was found. Initialize it with default values:
Axy = {-Inf, -1, -1};
parfor i=1:10
    for j=1:10
        % calculate the new value of "A(i,j)"
        tmp = rand();
        % Update the running maximum
        Axy = iReduce(Axy, {tmp, i, j});
    end
end
end

function axy = iReduce(axy, candidate)
if candidate{1} > axy{1}
    axy = candidate;
end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would do what I want. I have edited the question to add the code and the error.